# ImportError with cx_Freeze and pyinstaller

Tags: python, twisted, pyinstaller, cx-freeze

I was using pyinstaller before to try and get my app with twisted as an executable, but I got this error when executing:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cx_Freeze/initscripts/Console.py", line 27, in <module>
    exec code in m.__dict__
  File "client_test.py", line 2, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Twisted-13.0.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/__init__.py", line 53, in <module>
    _checkRequirements()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Twisted-13.0.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/__init__.py", line 37, in _checkRequirements
    raise ImportError(required + ": no module named zope.interface.")
ImportError: Twisted requires zope.interface 3.6.0 or later: no module named zope.interface.
```

So then, I tried using cx_freeze, but I get the **exact** same error, even when using `'namespace_packages': ['zope']` like [this example.](https://code.google.com/p/pythonxy/source/browse/src/python/cx_Freeze/DOC/samples/zope/qotd.py?repo=xy-27&r=11f515ac7e0b807a35c3be657333b794616e3601)

From where I'm building the executable, I can open a python interpreter and sucessfully import zope.interface, and I installed it through `easy_install`, then ran `pip install -U zope.interface` later on, which didn't have any effect.

Here's my `setup.py` for cx_freeze:

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

# Dependencies are automatically detected, but it might need fine tuning.
build_exe_options = {"excludes": ["tkinter"],
             'namespace_packages':['zope'],
            'append_script_to_exe':True
}

setup(  name = "exetest",
        version = "0.1",
        description = "My first executable",
        options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
        executables = [Executable("client_test.py")])
```

**EDIT 1:** Forgot to mention that I also tried putting a blank `__init__.py` file under `zope.interface`, and that also didn't help.

**EDIT 2:** When using cx_freeze, inside the library.zip of the build folder, zope.interface is in there and I don't think any of the modules are missing, but I still get the `ImportError`

This is from the output of cx_freeze:

```
Missing modules:
? _md5 imported from hashlib
? _sha imported from hashlib
? _sha256 imported from hashlib
? _sha512 imported from hashlib
? builtins imported from zope.schema._compat
? ctypes.macholib.dyld imported from ctypes.util
? dl imported from OpenSSL
? html imported from twisted.web.server
? netbios imported from uuid
? ordereddict imported from zope.schema._compat
? queue imported from twisted.internet.threads
? twisted.python._epoll imported from twisted.internet.epollreactor
? twisted.python._initgroups imported from twisted.python.util
? urllib.parse imported from twisted.web.server
? win32wnet imported from uuid
? wsaccel.utf8validator imported from autobahn.utf8validator
? zope.i18nmessageid imported from zope.schema._messageid
? zope.testing.cleanup imported from zope.schema.vocabulary
```

**EDIT 3:** Here's the sys.path output from my executable (shortened with the `..`)

```
['../build/exe.linux-x86_64-2.7/client_test',
 '../build/exe.linux-x86_64-2.7',
 '../build/exe.linux-x86_64-2.7/client_test.zip',
 '../build/exe.linux-x86_64-2.7/library.zip']
```

Here's the error I get when I import `zope.interface` directly:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cx_Freeze/initscripts/Console.py", line 27, in <module>
    exec code in m.__dict__
  File "client_test.py", line 3, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zope.schema-4.3.2-py2.7.egg/zope/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    __import__('pkg_resources').declare_namespace(__name__)
ImportError: No module named pkg_resources
```

**After adding `pkg_resources` to my includes in my cx_freeze setup.py, the program ran**

Comment: What about if you add `'packages':['zope.interface']` to your `build_exe_options`?

Comment: Tried it already, same exact error. I even added it to the `includes` and `namespace_packages` at the same time, too.

Comment: Is it installed in a .egg directory? cx_Freeze sometimes has trouble finding things in eggs (though it seems to have found twisted).

Comment: It's not, but it looks like it's loading a shared library called `_zope_interface_coptimazations.so`. Could that be breaking it?

Comment: All the python files for zope.interface are symlinks to a different directory, could that be it?

Comment: I don't think symlinks should make a difference, but check the file sizes within library.zip to make sure it's copied the real files. Also check that there's a `zope/__init__.pyc` in the zip file.

Comment: `zope/__init__.pyc` is there, and all the `.pyc` files are reasonable sizes.

Comment: Try importing `zope.interface` directly in your code, so you can see the original error, rather than the message from Twisted.

Comment: can you please dump your `sys.path` in the `client_test.py` file, before line 2?

Comment: @ThomasK, your last bit of advice helped me solve it. Make an answer saying to include `pkg_resources` and I'll accept it

Comment: @notbad.jpeg, you should be able to post an answer yourself and accept it, if you've found the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `pkg_resources` to your `includes` in your setup.py for cx_Freeze.

Comment: For PyInstaller in .spec file put `pkg_resouces` in `hiddenimports` list.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with cx_freeze. None of the above solutions seemed to work in my case.
For me this solution from [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/cx-freeze/mailman/message/26483012/) worked :

You need to actually create
`zope/__init__.py` as an empty file so that the normal processing
performed by imp.find_module() actually works

Answer (score 0):

Try adding to `build_exe_options` a specific include of the subpackage i.e. `"includes": ["zope.interface"],` this should force the inclusion of it.

Comment: Thanks, but this was mentioned in the comments on the question, I've tried it already.

Answer (score 0):

When I add 'pkg_resources' in includes and run the cx_freeze script, I only get these first two lines and it stays here :

running build

running build_exe

Comment: Someone has the same issue ?

Comment: Actually it is coming from this : namespace_packages = ['zope']

Comment: I added this in the includes and it now builds but I get a run time error when I try to run it :

Comment: I added this in the includes and it now builds but I get a run time error when I try to run it :  "twisted.internet", "twisted.internet.protocol"