# Dependancy with egg and building app with CX_freeze not being packaged

Tags: python, python-2.7, cx-freeze

I have a setup.py script that builds an .app file on OS X, however I need to include pyusb which was installed with pip. It's located `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packagespyusb-1.0.0a3-py2.7.egg` I am able to use it within my application however when I try to build and run it it doesn't include this dependancy. My setup script looks like:

```
application_title = "software" #what you want to application to be called
main_python_file = "./src/main.py" #the name of the python file you use to run the program

import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

includes = ["atexit","re"]

setup(
    name = application_title,
    version = "0.1",
    description = "Description",
    options = {"build_exe" : {"includes" : includes }},
    executables = [Executable(main_python_file, base = base)])
```

I've seen an answer of [adding pkg_resources to my includes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17531944/importerror-with-cx-freeze-and-pyinstaller/17685671#17685671) but from what I have tried this has had no success. So what do I need to include pyusb in my application file.

Comment: cx_Freeze has trouble finding things inside egg zip files. I have a pull request to fix this, but in the meantime, just unzip the egg and move its contents out to `site-packages`.

Comment: Thanks @ThomasK will I have to do this on all my platforms im building on?

Comment: Yep, unless you can install things so they're not in zipped eggs. My pull request to fix it is here: https://bitbucket.org/anthony_tuininga/cx_freeze/pull-request/38/finding-packages-inside-zip-files

Comment: @ThomasK How long until this pull request is likely to be merged? And then how long before its updated in pypi?

Comment: I'll ping Anthony to see about merging it, but I wouldn't expect a release for at least a few weeks - he's quite busy.